# Qt5.9.1 and Visual Studio 2015 adding Qt WebEngine module

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, qmake, qtwebengine

I'm new to QT and VS2015. I'm trying to run my first project that uses WebEngine module. I figured that I have to include line:

```
QT += webenginewidgets
```

in the qmake (.pro) file and add the module

```
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgets>
```

in my .cpp file.

But since Visual Studio doesn't use the .pro file how do I add a module to use the engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using the QtPackage addon you can right click your project and select 'Qt Project Settings'. In the window that appears go to the 'Add/Remove Qt Modules 2' tab and enable the 'WebEngineWidgets' module. Click OK and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for answering! And yes I'm using QtPackage addon yet I cannot find 'WebEngineWidgets' in the modules sections. Do you know how to add QT webEngine module to Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm marking the answer as correct, because indeed it answered my question.